# How to understand Jenkins and Git flow from testers perspective?

Tags: git, jenkins, automation, automated-tests, git-flow

1. There is a master branch with code from last release.
2. There is a dev branch.
3. Developers will create a new branch locally and work on feature branch.
4. They will write unit tests on their feature branch, if everything works well, they will send a pull request to dev branch.
5. The pull request is approved by admin.
6. Developer will now merge the code to dev branch.
7. Jenkins job will be trigged automatically and code will deploy on test environment.
8. I am assuming testers will start writing test cases for the test environment.

My question here is, do testers have a separate QA branch to write their test scripts? Just like developers, do testers also write tests in QAFeature1 branch and then send a pull request to QA branch, if it gets approved build will be triggered in Jenkins and then after everything goes well developers will merge it to master.

I don't understand Git and Jenkins flow for QA automation tester. I am working with forked project.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no right or wrong answer here. Your proposed solution is a possibility. But QA Feature branches should probably go into the develop branch as well, not directly to QA.

The best workflow I had, was when the automation tester writes the tests directly in the feature branch of the developer before it gets merged into the develop branch.
This ensures the developer didn't miss anything and avoids bugfixes later on. Introduced errors are not already a foundation of other features, and bugfixing usually is a lot faster and cheaper the earlier it is detected.
But all of this implies that the developer and tester work very close together and this is not always possible.

Comment: I wish I could +1 this more than once.  This is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to consider creating a QA separate repository for the tests scripts, since it has a different life-cycle